# Unchecked casting: Wildcard wrapped by Class to another type wrapped by Class

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm trying to collect Set of classes by Annotation criteria with reflections (for performance benetifs):

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packagePrefix);
Set<Class<Foo>> foos = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(BooAnnotation.class);
```

The problem is that I'm getting `Set<Class<?>>` instead of `Set<Class<Foo>>`.
I managed to check if the class is a type of `Foo` by filtering the collection with `.filter(Foo.class::isAssignableFrom)`.
At this point, I know that I'm working with classes that are of type `Foo`. Unfortunately when casting from `Class<?>` to `Class<Foo>` I am getting **Unchecked cast** and I want to avoid that.

Here is the full block of code:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packagePrefix);
Set<Class<Foo>> foos = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(BooAnnotation.class)
        .stream()
        .filter(Foo.class::isAssignableFrom)
        .map(uncheckedFoo -> {
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          Class<Foo> foo = (Class<Foo>) uncheckedFoo;
          return foo;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: the compiler cannot know that all BooAnnotation annotated classes are of type Foo. The warning must be accepted.

Comment: Yes, but I'm making sure that I have only classes that are extending Foo by Foo.class::isAssignableFrom. Is there a way to tell the compiler that I have Class<Foo> so it won't complain?

Comment: I played around with this a bit, and I couldn't find a way to avoid the unchecked cast warning. You may be stuck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Class<Foo>` is for the class object representing exactly the class `Foo`, and no other class. There can only be one object of type `Class<Foo>`. So having a `Set` of them makes no sense. It seems like you are collecting a `Set` of class objects representing `Foo` and its subclasses. In that case, it should be `Set<Class<? extends Foo>>`.

Second, you need to get `uncheckedFoo` of type `Class<?>` to `Class<? extends Foo>`. If you don't want to do with with an unchecked cast, you can do this in a type-safe way using `Class::asSubclass()`. So you can do something along the lines of:

```
Set<Class<? extends Foo>> foos = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(BooAnnotation.class)
        .stream()
        .filter(Foo.class::isAssignableFrom)
        .map(uncheckedFoo -> uncheckedFoo.asSubclass(Foo.class))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a good old **loop instead of a stream** to make clear to the compiler that each item is `assignableFrom` `Foo` when casting. Otherwise it forgets that all items are of type `Foo` in the next step.

**Cast checking and casting have to must be in 1 step**

```
Set<Class<Foo>> foos = new HashSet<>();

for(Class<?> i : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(
                   BooAnnotation.class ) )
{
  if(Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(i))
  {
    foos.add(Foo.class.cast(i)); //cast from Foo.class
  }
}
```

*Note*: you can use `forEach` instead of the `for(:)` loop

Comment: Unfortunately `Foo.class.cast(i)` returns Object of type Foo, not Class<Foo>, so this solution is not working in my case.

Comment: is normal casting possible then?

Comment: Yes, `Class<Foo> foo = (Class<Foo>) uncheckedFoo;` is working, but it's throwing an "Unchecked cast" warning which I would like to avoid.